# React native scroll not functioning

Tags: react-native

Having trouble with the scrolling.

it will not scroll

Please help

https://github.com/weiqing-nic/react-native/tree/master

Comment: I tested your code in the GitHub. It wasn't easy. why you removed `.js` from files name? Also, `index.ios.js` was wrong and `package.json` was missing. By the way, it doesn't have a scroll problem.

Comment: here is your app example https://github.com/PiotrBerebecki/albums-app-react-native. You probabily have forgot to put flex: 1 in scrollview's parent view. Check index.ios.js: https://github.com/rickyPanzer/react-native-tutorial-albums/blob/master/index.ios.js